# Good game sequences

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given two games **A** and **B** and the constraints is that A can be played on odd minutes and B can be played on even minutes only. Like Play A on 1st second then on 3rd second, likewise for B.

Now good sequence is defined as:

(1) If games are played according to their rule i.e., A will be played on odd minutes and B is played on even minutes.

(2) A and B are not played alternatively in the whole sequence.

For e.g.,

AXAXA : X denotes no game played on that minute, good sequence.

ABXXXB : Good sequence because both are played according to rule as well as first A is played then B and then again B.

XXXX: Good sequence.

ABXXAB: Not good sequence.

Given the total number of minutes till which the game is played, calculate total number of good sequences. As the number can be quite large provide the answer modulo 1000000007.

I am doing it by creating every string and checking its correctness. It is O(2^n). I have got answers for fewer n as 2, 3, 5, 9, 18, 38, 82, 177, 379, 803,.... n starting from 1.

How do I do it through DP?

Comment: What about abxxxa

Comment: abxxxa would not be a valid sequence because a is played on even minute(6th) and also games are played alternatively as first a then b then a

Comment: the answer for n = 3 should be 7

Comment: for n=3, good sequences are only xxx, xxa, xbx, axx and axa whereas xba, abx and aba are not.

Comment: Ok i misread the question

Comment: "ABXXXB : Good sequence because both are played according to rule as well as first A is played then B and then again B." -  here first A and B are alternating so it is not a good sequence, How come it will come good sequence when adding B then

Answer (score 0):

does this code work for you, I have added a demo [here](http://ideone.com/ZLRoIl). please check it out

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
#define MOD 1000000007
int dp[100005][3][4]= {0};
int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    dp[1][0][1] = 1;
    dp[1][2][0] = 1;
    for(int i=2; i<=n; i++){
        if(i&1){
          dp[i][2][0] = dp[i-1][2][0];
            dp[i][0][1] = dp[i-1][2][0];
            dp[i][2][1] = (dp[i-1][0][1] + dp[i-1][2][1]);
            dp[i][1][3] = dp[i-1][1][3];
            dp[i][2][2] = (dp[i-1][1][2] + dp[i-1][2][2])%MOD;
            dp[i][0][3] = ((dp[i-1][1][2] + dp[i-1][2][2])%MOD + (dp[i-1][1][3] + dp[i-1][0][3])%MOD)%MOD;
        }
        else {
            dp[i][2][0] = dp[i-1][2][0];
            dp[i][1][2] = dp[i-1][2][0];
            dp[i][2][1] = (dp[i-1][0][1] + dp[i-1][2][1]);
            dp[i][1][3] = ((dp[i-1][0][1] + dp[i-1][2][1])%MOD + (dp[i-1][1][3] + dp[i-1][0][3])%MOD)%MOD;
            dp[i][2][2] = (dp[i-1][1][2] + dp[i-1][2][2])%MOD;
            dp[i][0][3] = dp[i-1][0][3];
        }
        // for(int j=0;j<=2;j++){
        //  for(int k=0;k<=3;k++){
        //    if(dp[i][j][k])
        //      printf("i=%d j=%d k=%d dp=%d\n",i,j,k,dp[i][j][k]);
        //  }
        // }
    }
    int p = 1;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
      p = (p*2) % MOD;
    }
    p = (p - dp[n][0][3] - dp[n][1][3] )%MOD;
    p = (p+MOD)%MOD;
    cout << p << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for n=3, good sequences are only xxx, xxa, xbx, axx and axa whereas xba, abx and aba are not.

Comment: No, this one also not good, the good sequence checking should be done correctly specially the alternate sequence of game playing this one just printing fibonacci

Comment: Added an explanation

Comment: just have an example of n=4 or 5 to check it

Comment: answer for 4 is 9 and 5 is 18, if you want I can give you all the good sequences for either of 4 or 5

Comment: tell me which sequence am I missing from {XXXX, XXXB, XXAX, XBXX, XBXB, AXXX, AXXB, AXAX}

Comment: the answer for n=3 was 5, out of which 2 were ending with a, so everyone except those 2 can have b and x as next variable while those 2 can have only x

Comment: AXXB would not be a good sequence as A and B are played alternatively, for n=4 set of sequences are {XXXX, XXXB, XXAX, XBXX, XBXB, AXXX, AXAX, AXAB, ABXB}

Comment: how have AXXB played alternatively ? and how is ABXB valid since AB is alternate in it

Comment: whole sequence should not be alternate there must be one instance of non-alternative playing of game and for AXXB, first you play game A on 1st minute and then on 4th minute you play game B so as overall B is played after A and there are no other instances of game so AB is an alternative sequence of game playing whereas in ABXB, ABB is not an alternative sequence as a whole so ABXB valid and AXXB not.

Comment: by that logic even XBAB should've been valid, the question is not at all clear

Comment: How?? for XBAB games you are playing is BAB. Is BAB not an alternative sequence ??

Comment: if ABX is not a valid sequence how can ABXB be?

Comment: How can ABX be valid you are considering X to be a part while checking the sequence of game played, there could not be a complete sequence where each game is followed up by the other one.

Comment: In ABX, B is followed up by A making it non-valid, In ABXB, one instance of B is followed up by B making it valid. I hope it must clear the doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Let say we have states

1. x, xx, - when adding b it leads to state 2, when a it leads to 3, when x no changes in state
2. xb, xbxbx , - when x no changes in state, b no changes in state, when a it leads to state 5
3. a, axa, - when x no changes in state, when a no changes in state, when b it leads to state 4
4. ab, xxab, abx - x no changes in state, for b it changes to state 2, should neglect adding a
5. xba, xbax - x no changes in state, for a it changes to 3, for b we should neglect adding b

So you solve by going from small range(length 1) to given range and keep counting the states while adding x or a,b.

Let see for length

1. adding a and x to empty string

   - State1 - 0 + 1 (x)
   - State2 - 0
   - State3 - 0 + 1 (a)
   - State4 - 0
   - State5 - 0

   Total 2
2. adding b and x

   - State1 - 1
   - State2 - 0 + 1 (from state1 by adding b)
   - State3 - 1
   - State4 - 0  + 1 (from state3 by adding b)
   - State5 - 0

   Total 4
3. adding a and x

   - State1 - 1
   - State2 - 1
   - State3 - 1 + 1 (from state1 by adding a to it)  + 1 (from state3 itself axa..)
   - State4 - 1
   - State5 - 0 + 1 (from stat2 by adding a to it)

   Total 7
4. Adding b  and x

   - State1 - 1
   - State2 - 1 + 1 (from state 1) + 1 (from state2 itself) + 1 (from state4)
   - State3 - 3
   - State4 - 1 + 3 (from state3)
   - State5 - 1

   `Total 13`
5. Adding a  and x

   - State1 - 1
   - State2 - 4
   - State3 - 3 + 1(from state1) + 3(from state3 itself) + 1(from state5)
   - State4 - 4
   - State5 - 1 + 4(from state2)

   `Total 22`

Complexity will be O (n)

*code will be added soon*

Comment: Can you please make it more clearer with an example explanation for either n=4 or 5 ?

Comment: Edited for n=4.